Are local complete intersections of small codimension necessarily (global) complete intersections?
Hartshorne's 1974 conjecture states that a smooth closed subvariety $X$ of $\mathbb{CP}^r$ of dimension $>2/3r$ is necessarily (globally) a complete intersection. Is anything interesting known about this conjecture?
Can it (maybe, in a weaker form) be true if one only assumes $X$ to be a local (set-theoretic) complete intersection?
If any counterexamples (that is, local set-theoretic complete intersections of small codimension that are not complete intersections) are known, I would like to know their lower cohomology.

Probably the two conjectures, for smooth and lci, are equivalent, at least in codimension 2. By the Serre construction, any codimension 2 lci subscheme of projective space is the zero set of a vector bundle of rank 2. Then twisting by power of O(1) gives a globally generated rank 2 bundle, and a zero set of a section here is smooth by Bertini.

There are many results about the cohomology and the homotopy groups of varieties of small codimension in projective space, even in the set-theoretic c.i. case. See for instance G. Lyubeznik. Etale Cohomological Dimension and the Topology of Algebraic Varieties. Annals of Mathematics 1993.

@EnnioMoricone Serre construction can be applied only if one knows that the Picard group is generated by hyperplane section. This is true for large enough dimension in codimension two and SMOOTH by a theorem of Barth. To the best of my knowledge no counter example is known even for lci.

@Mohan The Picard group of a low codimension subvariety IS generated by the hyperplane section, even just assuming that the variety is normal -- see Theorem 11.4 in the above mentioned paper by Lyubeznik.

Yes, but lci doesn't imply normal.

Does $2/3n$ mean $2r/3$?

Yes, this should be $2r/3$; sorry!
I will look at Lyubeznik's papers once again. Yet I doubt that he considers counterexamples of the sort I am interested in.
